# GNU make: text replacement at two places in the same string?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In a GNU makefile, I need to rename
`/infiles/signal_*.wav`
to
`/outfiles/out_signal_*.wav`

This works (using [subst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)):

```
SIGNALIN += $(wildcard /infiles/signal_*.wav)

TEMP += $(subst infiles,outfiles, $(SIGNALIN) )
SIGNALOUT += $(subst signal,out_signal, $(TEMP) )
```

Is there a better, one-line way that would not include the `TEMP` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap function calls:

```
SIGNALOUT += $(subst signal,out_signal,$(subst infiles,outfiles,$(SIGNALIN)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case there are not really *replacements at two places*. What you want is replace `/infiles/` at the beginning of each word by `/outfiles/out_`. And that's one place. Try:

```
SIGNALOUT := $(patsubst /infiles/%,/outfiles/out_%,$(SIGNALIN))
```